# Unexpected output via shell_exec

Tags: php, exec, background-process, shell-exec

I want to write a background task. so i write a basic script for seeing the working of the shell_exec The script is as follows:

```
<?php
$op = shell_exec("php -v");
echo $op;
echo "back to the test.php";
?>
```

Output should be the php version information but it prints the following unexpected output:

```
back to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.phpback to the test.php
```

it's print my current pages content 59-60 times and sometimes with `content-type:text/html` I have tried using another php file output is same

Then I have tried with linux commands like date,ls it works perfectly
Please help me to sort out this problem I couldn't make out what is wrong?

I have tried out the absolute paths to php also but no difference and also use other php function like system,exec etc.

**Edit Note:** I have changed the exec function to shell_exec because I have missplaced this The output which i displayed below is from shell_exec

**UPDATE**
 I have not get the solution of the problem but got the cause of the problem there is nothing problem in a script it's because of server. I have write to support center of the server but doesn't get the response So I think this question is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think exec and those kind of functions are disabled in your php.ini . You can check it by

```
if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
    echo "shell_exec is enabled";
} else {
    echo "shell_exec is disabled";
}
```

Open your php.ini and navigate to section disable_functions

If shell_exec is listed under there , remove it.

Then restart apache / php handler.

Also If Safe Mode is enabled this function will not be available. You need to disable it.

Comment: I get the shell_exec is enabled

Comment: and sir if the function doesn't exist it should gives the error call to undefined function...

Comment: I have done it and it doesn't solve my problem but it will definately helps to beginners for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for exec function is

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

So it is second argument $output which will be filled by output of command. Still it will return array not version as string. You need to parse that data to get version.

```
exec("/usr/bin/php -v", $out);
print_r($out);
```

Also I suggest to use full path for php in exec function.

Comment: thank you @kuldeep.kamboj but it doesnt work above same output is coming but in array format

Comment: Yes as I say it will come as array output. You need to parse first array index ( or other as you check array) for getting version only.

Comment: but the output is same as above in my post i displayed just in array format

Comment: From manual page -> `The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or the command produces no output.` .  So if any error occurred you return will be null. You should check if command is working. I would again suggest to use full php path not just php. In Linux Ubuntu, It is mostly at /usr/bin/php but you still check where it installed.

Comment: I have also given the full path to the php location